# how to insert image on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have create a form, and I want to insert image when I click on the button "tester".
 This is my code :

```
<table id="table">
   <tr>
       <td id="col1">
           <form>

               <p><label for="text"> your text</label>:<input type="text" id="text"></input></p>

               <input type="submit" value="tester" onclick="addImage()" />
           </form>
       </td>
       <td id = "img"></td>
   </tr>
</table>




<script>
function addImage(){
    document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = "<img src='newWatermark.png'/>"
}
</script>


<style>
#table{width:100%}
#col1{width:50%}

</style>
```

It's work but just half a time ... And just during a few second ...
I don't understand why

Moreover I think that when I click on the button I refresh the page. 
In the URL I have : `/watermark.html` at the beginning and `/watermark.html?your+text=` when I click on the button.
But I just want to add an image on the same page. How can I do this?

Comment: `<input type="button" value="tester" onclick="addImage()" />`

Comment: ok thank you rayon it'w working!

Answer (score 0):

You submitting Your form.

Change type of input from `submit` to `button`.

Comment: It's working thank you razzka! But what is the differents between submit and button ?

Comment: Submit action sends Your form (with all inputed data) to the server, and reload this page with server's response. Usually, You have to handle submit at server side and reloaded page contains some new data. If (for some reason) You wants to submit form, but not refresh page, add `onclick="return false"` to <input> tag.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid page refresh use input type `button` not `submit`

```js
function addImage(){
    document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = "<img src='newWatermark.png'/>"; //This will overwrite previous image
}

function appendImage(){
   document.getElementById("img").innerHTML += "<img src='newWatermark.png'/>"; //This will append image
}
```

```css
#table{width:100%}
#col1{width:50%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
   <tr>
       <td id="col1">
           <form>

               <p><label for="text"> your text</label>:<input type="text" id="text"></input></p>

               <input type="button" value="tester" onclick="addImage()" />
               <input type="button" value="Append" onclick="appendImage()" />
           </form>
       </td>
       <td id = "img"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```